# Mysql ForeignKey constraint fails even if key exist

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in a mysql DB version 8.0.20 on Amazon RDS with a foreign key between them.

when I try and insert into the second table I get a foreign key error but I made sure that the key exists in the first table.

```
SELECT id_column FROM db.table1 WHERE id_column='123';
+------------+
| id_column  |
+------------+
| 123        |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I run:

```
INSERT INTO db.table2 (foreign_id, ...) VALUES ('123', ...);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`table2`, CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id_column`))
```

So if the ID exists in table1 why can't table2 use it in the foreign key column? what am I missing?

Comment: Data type problem? Try `... VALUES (123, ...);` to specify that value as an integer, not a string.

Comment: Thanks! the data types were varchar(16) and varcahr(32) I changed the 16 to 32 and it works!
please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Thanks, the id is actually a hash of digits and letters so a varchar is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the data types match across all these operations:

- creation of both tables.
- creation of the foreign key and its index.
- insertion of rows into both tables.

Comment: In my case, one table was InnoDB, the other was MyISAM